# Redirect drupal site to login page

Tags: drupal-7

I want to rediect my drupal site to its login page. While user open the site it get redirected to the login page in my drupal 7.

```
   Site url - abc.com
   Req url  - abc?q=user
```

Comment: Do you have Clean URLs turned on?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50300/how-to-redirect-anonymous-users-to-login-page-using-rules-module

You can use Rules for that. 
Detect if the user is authenticated and if this is the case, redirect him/her to the Login page.

**Events**: Drupal is initializing

**Conditions**:

1. User has role(s) - *Parameter: User: [site:current-user], Roles:
   anonymous user*
2. NOT Text comparison - Parameter: Text: [site:current-page:url],
   Matching text: user/login

**Actions**: Page redirect - Parameter: URL:
    user/login

Comment: Totally upvoted his answer over mine. This has the benefit of meeting exactly your request, without side effects and maintaining an additional module only for the sake of the current need. I find rules to be on of those things that I always think of last, but should be thinking of first.

Answer (score 0):

set the front page to login. You can do the same from site information settings in admin section.

Comment: While this gets the OP what he's asking for, it would mean the home page, even for authenticated users, would be /user; I'm not sure if that's an unintended consequence that he'd want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the [front](https://www.drupal.org/project/front) module. It will let you set the front page, per user role. Then you can make the unauthenticated users default front page /user and keep the others as is, or give them their own unique ones.

Another thing to consider, since I don't know exactly what your use case is, is to use the login block; then unauthenticated users will still only see what they're allowed, have the prompt to log in, and the block will no longer show up once they sign in.